# how to prove the correctness of a c program with coq

Tags: c, theorem-proving

I want to prove the correctness of some of my programs but I don't know where to start. Let's say I have the following program, how can I prove its correctness or lack there of. How can I go from the source below and plug them into a theorem prover. Coq or ACL2 or pretty much anything.

The code below just counts the bytes that it reads from the standard input. It has 2 versions, one does a byte by byte count, the other reads them by unsigned integer size chunks when possible. I know it's not portable or pretty, it's just an example that could get me started. With some help.

The code works and I know it's correct and I know how to write unit tests for it but I don't know how to prove anything about it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned count_bytes1(unsigned char * bytes, unsigned len) {
    unsigned count=0;
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        count+=bytes[i];
    }
    return count;
}
unsigned count_word(unsigned word) {
    unsigned tmp = word;
    if (sizeof(unsigned)==4) {
        tmp = (0x00FF00FFU&tmp) + (( (0xFF00FF00U)&tmp)>>8);
        tmp = (0x0000FFFFU&tmp) + (( (0xFFFF0000U)&tmp)>>16);
        return tmp;
    }
    if (sizeof(unsigned)==8) {
        tmp = (0x00FF00FF00FF00FFU&tmp) + (( (0xFF00FF00FF00FF00U)&tmp)>>8);
        tmp = (0x0000FFFF0000FFFFU&tmp) + (( (0xFFFF0000FFFF0000U)&tmp)>>16);
        tmp = (0x00000000FFFFFFFFU&tmp) + (( (0xFFFFFFFF00000000U)&tmp)>>32);
        return tmp;
    }
    return tmp;
}
unsigned count_bytes2(unsigned char * bytes, unsigned len) {
    unsigned count=0;
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0;i<len;) {
        if ((unsigned long long)(bytes+i) % sizeof(unsigned) ==0) {
            unsigned * words = (unsigned *) (bytes + i);
            while (len-i >= sizeof(unsigned)) {
                count += count_word (*words);
                words++;
                i+=sizeof(unsigned);
            }
        }
        if (i<len) {
            count+=bytes[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main () {
    unsigned char * bytes;
    unsigned len=8192;
    bytes=(unsigned char *)malloc(len);
    len = read (0,bytes,len);
    printf ("%u %u\n",count_bytes1(bytes,len),count_bytes2(bytes,len));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well the `correctness` you talk about, it's pretty hard to guarantee since in between execution and the code you have the `compiler`. You'd have to make sure that one also produces code that is guaranteed to maintain correctness. You also mention portability, well you can't take that out of the equation either. Different architectures have different `type-sizes`. I'm fairly sure you need to **limit** your set to a specific compiler(-version), specific arch, specific OS etc to make it remotely possible to prove anything.

Comment: Does your code assume that a `char` is exactly 8 bits? It seems that way.

Comment: I know this small example doesn't account for a lot of things, I could account for them. I'm not interested in proving this example. I want to learn how to do it in general. This example is just that, example, something to start with. I know some software has been proven correct and I want to be able to do it too.

Comment: let's say we can assume the following: the C or C++ standard or a subset of the standard is defined, we have a compiler that we know works, we have a machine that executes machine code correctly. -- how can we prove the program itself is working correctly, how do we define what we mean by correct, for starters we can assume correct means count_bytes1 and count_bytes2 always return an identical result.

Comment: You need to define the program, first. The code above is not an example of a specific definition of a program, because the output varies from system to system. Unless the definition of the program permits that variation, this program can't be "correct".

Comment: how do I define the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Know what you are proving: specification

First, decide what it is you want to prove for your function. For instance, write a contract for your function, using the [ACSL](http://frama-c.com/acsl_tutorial_index.html) specification language:

```
/*@ ensures \result >= x && \result >= y; 
    ensures \result == x || \result == y; 
*/ 
int max (int x, int y);
```

### 2. Verification

Then, you may prove that your implementation satisfies the specification, for instance with Frama-C's [WP plug-in](http://frama-c.com/wp.html).

The WP plug-in will generate proof obligations, the verification of which will ensure that the implementation is correct with respect to the specification. You can prove these in Coq 8.4+ if it amuses you (but almost nobody who actually does this does not first apply available, fully automatic SMT provers such as [Alt-Ergo](http://alt-ergo.lri.fr/)).

---

PS: it appears that you are trying to prove that one C function is equivalent to another, that is, to use a simple C function as specification for an optimized one. Proving the equivalence of one with respect to the other is the approach followed in this article:

José Bacelar Almeida, Manuel Barbosa, Jorge Sousa Pinto, and Bárbara Vieira. 
Verifying cryptographic software correctness with respect to reference implementations. In FMICS’09, volume 5825 of LNCS, pages 37–52, 2009.